# How to use Leave 2 Out Cross Validation method for fitting?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

How can I test that my model fits well using Leave $k$ Out Cross Validation for $k=2$? That means I take out the first 2 data points and fit the model for the rest of the data to find parameters, and use the two data points for checking, and doing this 6 times. Thanks in advance.

Here is my data and model.

```
data={{1.*10^-10,2.58022},{7.,2.66034},{7.33333,3.18999},{7.66667,3.88375},{8.,4.13342},
      {8.33333,4.21529},{8.66667,4.22846},{9.,4.2579},{9.33333,4.28118},{9.66667,4.28596},
      {10.,4.29661},{11.,4.31207}};

parameters = {γ, ε, k, c, p, is}; 

f[x_] := (E^-k γ)/(1 + c/(1 + (x/is)^p) + E^-k) + ε 

model = Sum[( f @ data[[i, 1]] - data[[i, 2]])^2, {i, 10}]

fit = NMinimize[{model, γ > 0 && c > 0 && p > 0 && 0 < is <= 11}, parameters] // Chop
Thread[{γ, ε, k, c, p, is} = parameters /. Last @ fit];
Show[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 11.02}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
          ImageSize -> 350], ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

Comment: This gives desired result for partitioning the data.
   

data = TakeDrop[data1, {#, # + 1}] & /@ Range[1, 12, 2]

Comment: What you want seems to be "leave $k$ out" and not $k$-fold...

Comment: Probably you are right..

Comment: This seems work but there is some glitch I could not fix. Can some one help me out? Thanks..

Do[model[j] = 
  Sum[( f@(Last@data[[j]])[[i, 1]] - (Last@data[[j]])[[i, 2]])^2, {i, 
    1, 10}];
 fit[j] = 
  NMinimize[{model[j], \[Gamma] > 0 && c > 0 && p > 0 && 
      0 < is <= 11}, parameters] // Chop;
 Thread[{\[Gamma], \[Epsilon], k, c, p, is} = 
   parameters /. Last@fit[j]];
 err[j] = 
  Total@Abs[
    f@(First@data[[j]])[[All, 1]] - (First@data[[j]])[[All, 2]]];
 Print[err[j]], {j, 1, 6}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, here's one way to do leave-$m$-out cross-validation, and returning the mean absolute deviation for each attempt in the process:

```
m = 2;
Table[Block[{model},
            model = NonlinearModelFit[Complement[data, test],
                                      {(E^-k γ)/(1 + c/(1 + (x/is)^p) + E^-k) + ε,
                                       γ > 0 && ε > 0 && p > 0 && 0 < is < 11},
                                      {γ, ε, k, c, p, is}, x, 
                                      Method -> {NMinimize, MaxIterations -> 150}];
            Norm[test[[All, 2]] - (model /@ test[[All, 1]]), 1]/2],
      {test, Subsets[data, {m}]}]
```

Note that this is more exhaustive than the use of `TakeDrop[]`, since the validation is being done with all the $\binom{n}{m}$ possible $m$-subsets of the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {{1.*10^-10, 2.58022}, {7., 2.66034}, {7.33333, 
3.18999}, {7.66667, 3.88375}, {8., 4.13342}, {8.33333, 
4.21529}, {8.66667, 4.22846}, {9., 4.2579}, {9.33333, 
4.28118}, {9.66667, 4.28596}, {10., 4.29661}, {11., 4.31207}};

data = TakeDrop[data, {#, # + 1}] & /@ Range[1, 12, 2];

f[j_, x_] := (E^-k[j]   \[Gamma][j])/( 1 + c[j]/(1 + (x/is[j])^p[j]) + E^-k[j]) + \[Epsilon][j];

crossVal[j0_] :=  Module[{j = j0},   model[j] =Sum[( f[j, (Last@data[[j]])[[i, 1]]] - (Last@data[[j]])[[i, 2]])^2, {i, 1, 6}];   fit[j] = NMinimize[{model[j], \[Gamma][j] > 0 && \[Epsilon][j] > 0 &&
    p[j] > 0 && 0 < is[j] <= 11}, {\[Gamma][j], \[Epsilon][j], 
  k[j], c[j], p[j], is[j]}] // Chop;  Thread[{\[Gamma][j], \[Epsilon][j], k[j], c[j], p[j], 
 is[j]} = {\[Gamma][j], \[Epsilon][j], k[j], c[j], p[j], 
  is[j]} /. Last@fit[j]];  err[j] =    Total@Abs[  f[j, (First@data[[j]])[[All, 1]]] - (First@data[[j]])[[All, 2]]];  Return[err[j]]]Table[crossVal[i], {i, 6}]
```

Comment: Here how I did.. It is not fancy but it does the job..